# How to get matplotlib figure size

Tags: python, matplotlib, size, pixel, figure

For a project, I need to know the current size (in pixels) of my matplotlib figure, but I can't find how to do this.
Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.plt
fig = plt.figure()
size = fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi # size in pixels
```

To do it for the current figure,

```
fig = plt.gcf()
size = fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi # size in pixels
```

You can get the same info by doing:

```
bbox = fig.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
width, height = bbox.width*fig.dpi, bbox.height*fig.dpi
```

Comment: Thank you, it gives me the size of the figure when first plotted I think, but it does not actualize if I change the size of my window and re draw my figure :/

Comment: it does for me. I first turned interactive plotting on `plt.ion()`. I created a figure `fig`. `size = fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi` returned `array([ 640.,  480.])`. I resized it and recalculated the size and got `array([ 704.,  270.])`

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate this way so. I just need to turn interactive plotting on now in my FigureCanvas :)

Comment: is `fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi` width or height?

Comment: @JosephGarvin both: `fig_width, fig_height = plt.gcf().get_size_inches()`

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this animation might help:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It should only illustrate the connection between dpi and figure_size, as an addition to the already good answer from Julien Spronck, however, If you don't find this useful, I can also remove this answer again.

Comment: I think it would be useful and pretty cool if you put code.

Comment: here is the code: https://manimplotlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manimplotlib4.html

Answer (score 10):

**Quickly extract figure size in inches**

To get width and height in inches I just use:

```
fig_width, fig_height = plt.gcf().get_size_inches()
print(fig_width, fig_height)
```

I put this here because this question is the first result that pops up when you search 'get matplotlib figure size', and the api most naturally works in inches, not pixels.